# How are umbilical connectors held in place until their intended detachment?

Tags: launch-site, engineering, launchpad, equipment, mechanisms

When a rocket is on its launch pad, umbilicals allow the flow of liquids, gases, electric power, and signals to the spacecraft.  The umbilical is detached from the spacecraft at or before launch, to allow the craft to move unimpeded.

**What mechanisms are used to hold umbilicals in place, so they do not detach prematurely?**

If your answer is specific to a particular spacecraft, please specify it.  Although this question is principally about umbilicals used for launch, their use between sections of a spacecraft may also be addressed.

Speculated possible answers:

- Friction is sufficient to hold the umbilical in place
- A spring-loaded or detent mechanism is overcome with the force of the launch
- Explosive bolts
- They are screwed-on
- A locking mechanism that must be actively released by electrical/pneumatic/hydraulic power
- Don't worry about it (doubtful)
- Just let the force of the launch tear through the pipes and wires (doubtful!)

---

Related questions:

- [Technology for LH2 & LOX umbilicals for rockets](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/9217/26446)
- [Fuelling LH2/LOX conectors for Rockets - is it easy to manually attach to the intake nozzles?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/9219/26446)
- [What holds SpaceX’s rocket in place in this launch?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/28008/26446)
- [How are the liquid propellant umbilical cord protected from the exhaust?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32167/26446)

Comment: Explosive bolts tend not to be used particularly closely to fuel lines, for some reason.

Comment: Yeah, the intent of my "speculated possible answers" was to show examples of the kind of answer I was looking for.  Some of those ideas are outright cringe-worthy.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137237/discussion-on-question-by-drsheldon-how-are-umbilical-connectors-held-in-place-u).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This [paper](https://commons.erau.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=https://www.google.com/&httpsredir=1&article=3435&context=space-congress-proceedings) surveys a large number of umbilical designs.

For the mechanical connections to the vehicle, it lists two types of detachable locking devices.

> The   type   of   locking   mechanism   used   in   this   application
>   is  shown  in  Figure  16.  This  system  is  a  simple ball and
>   socket type of locking device where a sleeve    captures    multiple   balls    around    the    ball  connection.  This  system,  used  in 
>   the  Saturn  program,  can be remotely disengaged by pneumatic
>   actuation as well as a  mechanical device.

[image]

> A  second  type  of  locking  mechanism  used  for  locking/release is
>   the collet. This type of device uses a pin  to  radially  expand 
>   fingers  that  are  captured  by  the  flight      side receptacle      (Figure      17).      During      disengagement,  the
>   pin  is  pulled,  releasing  the  fingers  from  the  receptacle.  For
>   conditions  where  the  pin  is  jammed, a secondary system provides
>   additional force for release. As a third option the vehicle receptacle
>   can have  a  shear  pin  designed  to  fail  at  a  given  load.  This
>   design  has  been  used  extensively  on  current  vehicles.

[image]

The paper lists Shuttle and Atlas V as users of the collet mechanism.

This image labels one of the collet connections at the top of the shuttle port side (LH2) T-0 umbilical, and shows both the vehicle and ground side plates.

[image]

This personal photo shows the complete starboard side (LO2) T-0 umbilical so that you can clearly see there are two collect connections at the top (right side in this picture since the vehicle was sitting on its gear).

[image]

Comment: Does spacex also uses the same kind of umbilical cord or have they developed their own systems